# Error on trying to launch a code for stm32L4 developement board

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide

I have started to work with STM32L4 Kameleon development board and got a problem right away. I created project for my board and generated sample code for it
When I run it a ST-Link USB connector diode is blinking but after a few seconds I get an error:

```
Error in final launch sequence:

Failed to execute MI command:
load D:\\STM32CubeIDE\\workspace_1.13.2\\start\\Debug\\start.elf 

Error message from debugger back end:
Error finishing flash operation
Failed to execute MI command:
load D:\\STM32CubeIDE\\workspace_1.13.2\\start\\Debug\\start.elf 

Error message from debugger back end:
Error finishing flash operation
Failed to execute MI command:
load D:\\STM32CubeIDE\\workspace_1.13.2\\start\\Debug\\start.elf 

Error message from debugger back end:
Error finishing flash operation
Error finishing flash operation
```

Start is the name of my project.

And here is what I get on IDE's terminal:

```
STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 7.4.0
Copyright (c) 2023, STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.

Starting server with the following options:
        Persistent Mode            : Disabled
        Logging Level              : 1
        Listen Port Number         : 61234
        Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
        Verbose Mode               : Disabled
        SWD Debug                  : Enabled
        InitWhile                  : Enabled

Waiting for debugger connection...
Debugger connected
Waiting for debugger connection...
Debugger connected
Waiting for debugger connection...
Encountered Error when opening D:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2\STM32CubeIDE\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.cubeprogrammer.win32_2.1.0.202305091550\tools\bin\STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe
Error in STM32CubeProgrammer
Shutting down...
Exit.
```

Comment: I encounter this problem when my wiring from the st-link to the MCU has a problem (loos connection). Recheck your connection and restart the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-products/stm32g473rc-error-in-launch-sequence-when-flash-file-gt-128kb/td-p/603410) the same issue you have? It seems like it's a bug in the latest version of STM's CubeIDE. There is a suggested fix as the answer of that post, but I assume that you could also downgrade CubeIDE to a previous version.

Comment: I downgraded to 1.10.0 and still nothing has changed